# Xcode 13 Bridging Header does seem to find my Obj-C classes

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I know this question might have been posted multiple times, but I haven't find any solution for 2 days despite looking closely all the answers in here.

I have an Objective-C data model I want to use in my Swift application.

So when adding my *DataModel.m* in my **Models** folder, it created *MyApp-Bridging-Header.h* inside the **Models** folder as well.

[image]

I try several things in the Bridging-Header file to import my **ProjectModel.h** like:

> #import "ProjectModel.h"

> #import "Models/ProjectModel.h"

> #import "MyApp/Models/ProjectModel.h"

But none seems to works as I would like.

The Bridging-Header file is defined as well in the Build Settings (see below)

[image]

[image]

But as soon as I try to compile the project I keep having the error: **Cannot find type 'ProjectModel' in scope** (like below)

[image]

And when using auto-completion on ProjectModel I got this warning:

[image]

I don't know what I am missing right now, I would appreciate any help, plus, I'd rather specify, I am doing this on *macOS Monterey* with *Xcode 13.1*.

Comment: Can we look at the file that produces error?

Comment: Actually it's any Swift file that try to instantiate a *ProjectModel*, but sure I can provide you a screen shot :)

Comment: Ok, may be `ProjectModel.h` is empty?

Comment: He is not empty, do you want also a screenshot ?

Comment: May be there is two files with same name?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a very small demonstration project and post it?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line at the beginning of the **Swift** file that uses the model:

```
import ProjectModel
```

Comment: You can import Classes the same way you import a Framework ?